# PHP Variables in SQL Statement not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a SQL query with a PHP variable, which is a username. For some reason, nothing happens when it is executed. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
mysqli_query($dbcon, "ALTER TABLE ipList");
mysqli_query($dbcon, "ADD ".$userName." VARCHAR(30)");
```

Thanks!

~Carpetfizz

Comment: it should be in a single line, `ALTER TABLE ipList ADD ".$userName." VARCHAR(30)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's one command. Put it all in one call to query:

```
mysqli_query( $dbcon, "ALTER TABLE ipList ADD ".$userName." VARCHAR(30)" );
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will accept your answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: I've updated the answer and changed it to `mysqli` but feel free to change it as your liking :)

Answer (score 1):

Your query should look like:

```
mysqli_query($dbcon, "ALTER TABLE ipList ADD ".$userName." VARCHAR(30)");
```

But, it seems to me that your database structure is not entirely true.

Do you want each user to create a separate column?

Comment: Yeah, I'm essentially trying to accomplish what a graph db does in a relational database.